# attribute 'font-size' alters the 'background-img' size as well

Tags: html, css, background-image, font-size, background-size

I am trying to make a site, using a background image:
(CSS)

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("../img/clouds.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 760%;
}
```

and I also have on the top of the page this:
(HTML)

```
<div class="pageTitle">
    <p>Title of Page basically</p>
</div>
```

(CSS)

```
.pageTitle {
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

When I try to make the font-size bigger, the background image grows as well (looks like it's zoomed in, basically).

I suppose this has to do with the usage of percentages, but even when using `em` notation or `px` I still get the same result.
How can I make the `pageTitle` bigger without altering my background image's size?

What seems to make it work is altering the `background-size: 100% 760%;` to `background-size: 100% 250%;` (in my case), but still, whenever an element is altered it needs fixing as a whole.

Code Snippet:

```js
var currentQuote = '';
var availableQuotes = [ 'bla','blo','ble','foo','bar'
];

function setRandomQuote() {
 currentQuote = availableQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuotes.length)];

 $('#quote').html(currentQuote);
 $('#tweetQuote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + currentQuote).attr('target', '_blank');
}

$(function () {
 $('#randomQuote').click(function () {
  setRandomQuote();
 });
});
```

```css
.w3-tangerine {
 font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
 font-size: 200%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
}
body {
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/850674/pexels-photo-850674.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=agriculture-animal-photography-animals-850674.jpg&fm=jpg");
 background-size: 100% 250%;
}
p {
 font-size: 100%;
}
#randomQuote, #tweetQuote {
 margin: 3% 1% 3% 1%;
}
#quote {
 margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
    </head>

<body>

  <div class="w3-tangerine">
 <p>Just Another Random Quote Generator</p>
</div>
<div id="quote">
 Click on the button to generate a quote!
</div>
<div>
    <input id="randomQuote" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate a Quote!">
    <a id="tweetQuote" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Tweet this Quote  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with all the relevant code and the image hosted online? Thanks

Comment: Or better yet, create a code snippet directly on StackOverflow - it's built into the question editor.

Comment: Added the snippet, but I don't seem to be able to upload a background image in order to show the issue.
EDIT: Image uploaded.

Comment: Upload to [Imgur](https://imgur.com) and use the image link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without set the `height` of a `body` the precent of `height` of the `background` is as a `height` of a contant. so 760% `background-height` is `text-height`*7.6. it is why when you change the size of the image the size of the image grow too..
 what you can do is set

```
 html, body{
    height:100%;
    }
```

and then it wil calculate precent of the whole page size (so in your case you will see only 1/7.6 of the height of the image).

Comment: That explains a lot, and also solved the issue! Thank you!

Comment: I had the same solution, here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhq3akhn/) if you want to take a look at it, @Zap.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it also makes sense to have the body as `background-size: 100% 100%; ` instead of the weird percentages I used to cover up the issue.

Comment: yap, honestly i not realy understand the resone of this precent, just answer the quetion ) if you want it to not strach you can use `background-size:cover;`

Answer (score 1):

There's an [article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), which describes the exact problem, that you have.

One of the solutions is to provide the following attribute to `body`. This will ensure everywhere is covered:

```
body {
  ...
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This means that the image will cover as much as possible on the screen, but what if the ratio isn't the same? Would then the image stretch so it fits the size it might be lacking? 
Thanks for the article, though!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currentQuote = '';
var availableQuotes = [ 'bla','blo','ble','foo','bar'
];

function setRandomQuote() {
 currentQuote = availableQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuotes.length)];

 $('#quote').html(currentQuote);
 $('#tweetQuote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + currentQuote).attr('target', '_blank');
}

$(function () {
 $('#randomQuote').click(function () {
  setRandomQuote();
 });
});
```

```css
.w3-tangerine {
 font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
 font-size: 200%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
}
   

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }
body {
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/850674/pexels-photo-850674.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=agriculture-animal-photography-animals-850674.jpg&fm=jpg");
 background-size: cover;
}
p {
 font-size: 100%;
}
#randomQuote, #tweetQuote {
 margin: 3% 1% 3% 1%;
}
#quote {
 margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
    </head>

<body>

  <div class="w3-tangerine">
 <p>Just Another Random Quote Generator</p>
</div>
<div id="quote">
 Click on the button to generate a quote!
</div>
<div>
    <input id="randomQuote" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate a Quote!">
    <a id="tweetQuote" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Tweet this Quote  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So basically you added the `html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }` as indicated above yes?

Comment: Yes and also 
body {
 background-size: cover
  }

Comment: So the combination of the two replies I've received, nice! Thanks for your contribution.